# Your calendar couldn't be refreshed (Operation: CalDAVRefreshDelegateListQueueableOperation)

Tags: calendar, mojave, ical

After upgrading to the latest Mojave update [10.14.3[, I got this error prompt when attempting to sync my calendar.

[image: A snapshot of the error message]

Temporarily, I'm using Fantastical as my Calendar, But really prefer the Calendar.app over Fantastical.

Anyone got it too? How should I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

- Under `Preferences > Accounts` I unchecked `Enable this account` for each of my accounts
- I then closed the Calendar application completely (`cmd+q`)
- After re-opening Calendar, I rechecked `Enable this account` for each account

and everything seems to work now!

Comment: Code formatting unneeded here.

Answer (score 2):

## Sign out of iCloud

To fix this sign out of iCloud in the preferences pane. No data will be lost and all will be retrieved when you sign back in again. If you use iCloud Keychain, when you sign back in to iCloud follow one of the procedures described in [this Support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5813) to set it up on an additional device.

## If that doesn't work

If signing out and in of iCloud doesn't work there are several other options you could try.

#### Re-enabling the calender account

You could try re-enabling the affected calender account. From the Calendar menu bar, select
Calendar ▹ Preferences ▹ Accounts.

Choose the affected account from the list on the left and uncheck the box marked. Then check it again to enable the account.

#### Add the account again with the same settings

You can make a note of the settings for that acxoint, then delete it and add it again with the same settings.

#### Check your settings

If you can't add the account, the settings may be invalid. Verify them. How you do that depends on what kind of account it is. If it's a Google calendar and you've activated 2-step verification, you need to generate an application-specific password in your Google account and enter it in place of your old password.

Comment: Have tried all of the steps you mentioned, still no luck :( Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @JonathanFilbert no problem. Have you tried updating your Mac or rebooting it?

Comment: Yes I have, multiple of times. And right now my Mac is in the latest version of Mojave. Still no luck.

Comment: Also getting this same issue.  Eventually the calendars will refresh, but it sometimes takes a very long time.  Not sure what the cause of this is, but I'm getting it on both of my machines running MacOS Mojave 10.14.3.

Comment: Logging out of iCloud from a computer (Mojave, remember?) when one's Documents and Desktop folders are on the iCloud is a very bad idea, because that will make a local archive and remove the Document and Destop folders from the computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you own iOS devices running a recent iOS version, it is likely you will get compatibility issues due to OS X Mojave supporting only older iCloud technologies.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).